# Trying to use variable into command prompt using python and adb

Tags: python, android, adb

```
import os
import random 
xpixel = random.randint(359,402) 
ypixel = random.randint(256,368) 
trest = random.randint(10,16)
print(trest)
time.sleep(trest)
print(xpixel)
print(ypixel)
os.system('cmd /k adb.exe shell input tap xpixel ypixel') <----I know this part is absolutly wrong but the concept is to be able to input those two numbers into command prompt some how.
```

I'm trying to click on a point in a screen using python/ adb.
I know how to generate the random number, and also the adb command. I just don't know how to transfer those variables and make them useful in command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

While you can include variable values using f-strings

```
f'cmd /k adb.exe shell input tap {xpixel} {ypixel}'
```

it might be better if instead of using `adb` and `input` you use a more specific library like [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/) or any other, to be able to do something. like this

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import time
import random

from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient

device, serialno = ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit()
xpixel = random.randint(359,402)
ypixel = random.randint(256,368)
trest = random.randint(10,16)
print(trest)
time.sleep(trest)
print(xpixel)
print(ypixel)
device.touch(xpixel, ypixel)
```